# How to get div tag table button id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have buttons in table. the table is appended into div tag "divtag1". I am not able to access button id from div tag table using the below each statement. Kindly help me to get button if from div tag table.

```
$("#divtag1").children().each(function () {
}
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML code?

Comment: Use find(); instead.....

Comment: "button id" So use ID selector

Comment: so do you have the button's id and u wanna access the button using its id? or you are trying to find the id of a specific button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#divtag1 :button").each(function () {
}
```

Comment: And you. Why you think buttons are `input` elements?

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#divtag1").find("a").each(function () {
}
```

Comment: Why you think buttons is `a` elements?

Comment: @laaposto see his nickname "Think Different" ;)

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`  ;-)